Copy all changes from branch to master
I am new to git and I want to copy all changes made in a branch to the master branch.
Is there a way, how to do that, or do I have to use the merge command and compare both branches?
Here is a diagram of my git repo:
my git repo
Here is the tmp branch and the master branch and I want to go back to the master branch.
I have tried to merge.. but there are to many changes. And I have got a lot of errors. So that is why I am here.
EDIT: Now the tree looks like this:
new git tree
How can I go back to the HEAD?

Try using merge command after the rebase command-
- git checkout branch-name
- git rebase master
- git checkout master
- git merge branch-name

OR
Try using these commands -
- git pull --rebase origin
- Add a commit message to your file, using the command :-
  git commit -a -m "Your commit message"

 Then
- git push -u origin master


Could you format your anwser a bit, sorry can not read it :)

Nice, thanks.. I gonna try it

Now the git tree has changed.. have a look pls. In my question. I want to go back to HEAD

Can you please elaborate what you are trying to do? Also, HEAD is like a pointer that points out the current commit.

I try to push "hugo config" from the image to github, so that I can work from another computer on that repo. But I want that "hugo config" is the master branch and not the HEAD. Maby delete all commits, so that "hugo config" is the first on the tree. Hard to explain.

Were you trying to change Master branch directly? Or did you made commits to a remote repository? See, the answer I am getting from your question is that First you have to clone a project which is your remote repository and you made changes to that and then merge it to the master or main branch. I want to know that what your process is. Because the process I told is the correct one and also majority developers follow that only.

I have created a project/theme on my local computer with hugo and pushed that to github and netlify. Netlify gets my code from github and host it. I am new to git and I try to learn it. I switch between my notebook and desktop to get the worklflow. Normally i fetch the changes, but this time something went wrong and I have to switched the commits and then it starts to get messy.

Try using "git diff" command to track commit history. Refer this link for any confusions - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff
